# Local Notification Alert style set to 'Alerts' when phone is locked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

just wondering if it is possible to set the default notification style to 'Alerts' programtically, so the user would not need to change this in the phones sttings->Notifications.  Also is it possible to set the notification to 'Alert' for when the phone is locked? Thank you

Comment: No this is not possible, only the user can change the style of the notification.

Comment: And the 'alert' style notification can't be used when the phone is locked in any circumstance? (example would be for alarm clock that notification needs to be turned off to stop the notification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that's not possible,
That's an OS functionality, which is controlled only by user.